# Количество блоках на разных медиа-скринах

Tags: css, flexbox, html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="rest" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Макдоналдс — Газетный</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Бургеры</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">DimSum & Co — ЦДМ</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽ • Японская • Китайская • Азиатская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">40 - 50 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">ДвижОК — Манежная</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽ • Американская • Европейская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">35 - 45 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">НЯ — NHA</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Вьетнамская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">30 - 40 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Точка Дзы — Цветной</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽₽ • Вьетнамская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">40 - 50 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Cinnabon</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Выпечка • Десерты • Капкейки</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">PIZZELOVE</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Пицца</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">15 - 25 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Zю кафе — Тверская</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Японская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Bar BQ Cafe — Манежная</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽₽ • Европейская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">30 - 40 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Дано 9 блоков в родителе. На десктопе они отображаются как три строки по три блока. На планшетах - два столбца по 5 и 4 блока соответственно. А на мобайле должно отображаться только 4 блока одним столбцом. Каким образом это можно реализовать? Прятать лишние блоки display: none и потом перебивать на другом медиа-скрине?

Comment: Если это бутстрап, то там есть классы типа `.hidden-sm`, которые скрывают блок на необходимом разрешении

Comment: Используйте .row div:not(:nth-child(-n+4)), чтобы задать элементам следующим за 4-ым display: none или visibility: hidden. Здесь уже по требованиям. Ну и конечно же оберните в @media screen and (max-width: 767px) { ... } для медиа смартфонов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запиши медиа для смартфонов в конце файла стилей.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row div:not(:nth-child(-n+4)) {
    display: none !important;  // или visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mobileNone{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="rest" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Макдоналдс — Газетный</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Бургеры</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">DimSum & Co — ЦДМ</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽ • Японская • Китайская • Азиатская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">40 - 50 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">ДвижОК — Манежная</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽ • Американская • Европейская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">35 - 45 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">НЯ — NHA</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Вьетнамская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">30 - 40 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info mobileNone">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Точка Дзы — Цветной</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽₽ • Вьетнамская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">40 - 50 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info mobileNone">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Cinnabon</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Выпечка • Десерты • Капкейки</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info mobileNone">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">PIZZELOVE</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Пицца</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">15 - 25 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info mobileNone">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Zю кафе — Тверская</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽ • Японская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">25 - 35 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="restaraunt-list__info mobileNone">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <img class="restaraunt-list__photo" src="" alt="">
      <h2 class="restaraunt-list__name">Bar BQ Cafe — Манежная</h2>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__category">₽₽₽ • Европейская</p>
      <p class="restaraunt-list__time">30 - 40 Min</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

можно удалить через дополнительный класс!

Comment: Тогда прийдется через jQuery / JS делать проверку if (item > 4) { $(".row div").addClass("mobileNone"); }